# Python, Jupyter Notebook, Downloading an Excel File from a URL

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently trying to access some data from the ABS website.

https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/labour/earnings-and-work-hours/weekly-payroll-jobs-and-wages-australia/latest-release#data-download

Table 5.

The name of the excel file changes on every release. I would like to update it by automatically downloading it and saving it into a data frame.

Current progress:

Thank You Beautiful Soup. Used that Function to obtain a list of Url's on the website.

```
#####Step 1: start by importing all of the necessary packages#####
import requests #requesting URLs
import urllib.request #requesting URLs
import pandas as pd #for simplifying data operations (e.g. creating dataframe objects)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #for web-scraping operations

#####Step 2: connect to the URL in question for scraping#####
url = 'https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/labour/earnings-and-work-hours/weekly-payroll-jobs-and-wages-australia/latest-release' 
response = requests.get(url) #Connect to the URL using the "requests" package
response #if successful then it will return 200

#####Step 3: read in the URL via the "BeautifulSoup" package#####
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') 

#####Step 4: html print#####
for link in soup('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))

##how to get the link to table 5?##
**url = ?**

##last step to save into data frame##
ws = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name='Payroll jobs index-SA4', skiprows=5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find div class associate to the XSLX from URL and use `find_all` method to return list of elements and use index 1 for finding `href`

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/labour/earnings-and-work-hours/weekly-payroll-jobs-and-wages-australia/latest-release' 
response = requests.get(url) 
response 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') 

url=soup.find_all("div",class_="abs-data-download-right")[1].find("a")['href']
pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name='Payroll jobs index-SA4', skiprows=5,engine='openpyxl')
```

For finding all URL's:

```
urls=soup.find_all("div",class_="abs-data-download-right")
for i in urls:
    print(i.find("a")['href'])
```

Output:

```
https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/labour/earnings-and-work-hours/weekly-payroll-jobs-and-wages-australia/week-ending-31-july-2021/6160055001_DO004.xlsx
https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/labour/earnings-and-work-hours/weekly-payroll-jobs-and-wages-australia/week-ending-31-july-2021/6160055001_DO005.xlsx
....
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Sorry, would you be able to give a small explanation for the url line. For example, how would I change it to access a different table.  I can see the parsed html in the soup file but I still don't understand the url command/what it means.

Comment: See i have find all divs where XLSX means URL of excel file and then find the right one from list using indexing operation.